# Apex SQL complete freezes SQL management studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-management-studio

I am using SSMS 18.4

I installed APEX sql complete, and every 30 minutes it freezes my management studio.

So I'd have to go to Task Manager and end it from there.

Did anybody have issues like that?

Comment: Mine hangs when using it in table creation scripts...

Comment: Same here. I have not found a solution to this yet. If you do please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, only managed to stop it by disabling the ApexSQL autocomplete, which is not great as it is one of the main reasons I installed the tools, but at least you can use the rest of the features.

It seems to be a common problem: https://www.quest.com/community/apexsql/f/forum/30791/ssms-18-5-hang-with-latest-apexsql-complete